# Is "app.listen()" necessary when connecting a node script to my website?

Tags: node.js, express

I am still very new to web development so sorry if the answer is obvious!

Anyway, I have created a form for my website that lets users email me a request. I'm using `nodemailer` to do this in my `app.js` script. Also using `Express`, obviously. Anywho, during testing when I run the local server `'node app.js'` everything works fine, ie. I open up my `index.html` on `localhost:3000` and can successfully send myself an email through my form. Now I just have to add all the files to my website's cpanel public_html folder. AKA make it official.

THE QUESTION: Is `app.listen(*port number*)` necessary at all when I put `'app.js'` into my website's files? Will my `index.html` form still activate `'app.js'`, as long as it's available?

Again, still very new to this, at least the back-end stuff. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Since it looks like you're new here, you will generally get more accurate and more specific answers if you include the relevant portion of your code in your question.  That removes any question about exactly what you're doing and people can create answers that work with your exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is app.listen(port number) necessary at all when I put 'app.js' into my website's files?

Good question! In essence, it is indeed necessary. Your express server is a live process that requires input by listening to a port on your server and you can host this in many ways. If this process isn't running on your server, there would be no process running for your requests to be... well, processed!

Simply uploading it to your webserver of choice would essentially just be a JS file sitting on your webserver, very much lonely and without purpose! [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment) a nice summary to get you going on deploying an express server.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is curious, I just used PHPMailer to redo the whole thing (first time did it with Nodemailer). This way I don't have to deal with Node compatibility with my shared hosting service (Bluehost). I can just put the PHP file in there.

Comment: Yeah.... probably for the best. node.js isn't something you can just drop into any existing host and have it function, it has to be properly exposed to the outside world, either by opening up ports or proxying it through an existing port, and node.js actually has to be installed on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You don't show ANY of your code which makes it a bit hard for us to guess what you're doing.

You do have to start your web server somehow or there won't be any server process running and nothing to respond to incoming requests.  `app.listen(port)` is one such way to start the server when using Express.

You don't say what type of web hosting account you have, but it sounds like you may may be attempting to use a shared hosting account that does not specifically support node.js apps and might not be compatible with a node.js app.

You will need a hosting account that lets you have a long running server process (your node.js server process) and you will have to follow the hosting directions for how you configure the port on your server to match how their shared infrastructure works.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not providing enough information. Yes, I'm using Bluehost, a shared hosting platform. So I might have to use another method.